# Compare two lists, find old (removed) and new (added) values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Say I have the following, a list:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

At a point later, it's updated and might become, for example:

```
A
B
C
D
G
H
I
```

I need to find which new elements have entered the list, but ALSO which old elements have left the list, upon update. Of course this can be done with brute force (and a fair bit of code), but what would be the "standardised" (i.e sagacious) method for completing this task, minimally, with output as:

Entered list = G, H, I

Exited list   = E, F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use sets, they make lookups fast:

```
>>> old = 'ABCDEF'
>>> new = 'ABCDGHI'
>>> set(new) - set(old)
{'H', 'I', 'G'}
>>> set(old) - set(new)
{'F', 'E'}
```

Depends on your actual data, though, like whether you have duplicates (and if yes, how you want them treated) and whether you care about order and whether the list elements are hashable.

Comment: Yeah I'll go with the sets. Never crossed my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You said it can be done with brute force and it doesn't really seem like you want that, but it can be done with list comprehension in two lines.

```
entered = [i for i in x if i not in y]
exited = [i for i in y if i not in x]
```

This checks each item in each list and sees if it is in the other list. It then filters out which ones are not and puts them in a new list. The only possible problem with this is that each list check has a complexity of `O(n)`, so in total that is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: ... and it is, of course, *extremely important* that you very-clearly understand *when, and how* the "before" *vs.* "after" lists are constructed. (Be very certain, for example, that you always *have* a "before" list ... otherwise, that you are certain that you can *reliably recognize* when all of the cases where you don't.)  If you're sure of these things, then, as Michaelpri so aptly demonstrated, "the rest of it is easy."

Comment: More like O(n^2), no? The `in` test for lists is linear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module.Check the output for '+' and '-'.

You can make a deepcopy of of original list and compare the subsequent modified list

```
In [41]: import difflib

In [42]: d=difflib.Differ()


In [46]: a
Out[46]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

In [47]: b=['c','d','g']

In [48]: diff=d.compare(a,b)

In [49]: "".join(diff)
Out[49]: '- a- b  c  d+ g- e- f'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=[3,4,5,6]
>>> filter(lambda i: i not in b,a)
[1, 2]
>>> filter(lambda i: i not in a,b)
[5, 6]
```